# Wpf TextBox style with tooltip

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I want my text boxes to show a specific text as tool tip depending on the validation status. To do this I currently use the following code and it works:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding XPath=HelpText/Description, Mode=OneTime}" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

When there is no error, a description text read from an xml-file is displayed and when there is an error the validation error string is displayed.

The problem is that now I have to copy this style and apply it to every textbox (and change the XPath, it is unique for each text box), what I would want to do is put the style in Window.Resources so that I can just reference it for every text box like this:

```
<TextBox Name="textBox2" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyle}" />
```

But the XPath will be different for each textbox so I cannot just place my style in Window.Resources. How can I make an instance specific XPath available in the style? Is there a way to do this without creating a new text box and derive from TextBox? I was wondering if one could use an attached property in this case but I don't know how they work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't completely tested this, but you could use an attached property
Something like:

```
class ToolTipHelper {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToolTip", typeof(string) ...
```

Then you modify your trigger:

```
<Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="False">
  <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(ToolTipHelper.ToolTip}, Mode=OneTime}" />
</Trigger>
```

And you use it like

```
<TextBox ToolTipHelper.ToolTip="{Binding XPath=HelpText/Description, Mode=OneTime}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I cannot get the binding in the style to work, I have tried `<Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(local:ToolTipHelper.ToolTip), Mode=OneTime}" />` but I get the error "Property path is not valid. 'ToolTipHelper' does not have a public property named 'ToolTip'." I created ToolTipHelper according to [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753957.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1). Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Most likely you don't have provided the proper arguments to the RegisterAttached method. 1. Name of the property without "Property", 2. the type of the property value 3. the owner class of the property "ToolTipHelper" 4. the metadata with at least a default value.

Comment: Thank you I noticed I used the wrong owner class. I also had to change the binding mode to OneWay, when I used OneTime the tool tip always displayed the default text. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Tag Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) and change your style to

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then you bind the desired `XPath` to the `Tag` property of each specific `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Tag="{Binding XPath=HelpText/Description, Mode=OneTime}" />
```